# How to recover "Family Guy: The Quest For Stuff" game progress

Tags: google-play-games

My HTC 610 froze and could not be rebooted.  I had a game installed through google play and was continually signed in to the google acount.  I was told that as long as I was signed in, the game's progress would be saved.  I received my new HTC 610 today and signed in to google+, went into the google play menu, clicked on my apps and my games automatically transferred.  When I opened up a game, the progress was not there.  Is there any way to restore progress?

Comment: What game?  Would be helpful in figuring this out.

Comment: sorry.  Family Gut The Quest For Stuff

Comment: Did you connect through Facebook as well?  This is odd, as I just recently changed phones, signed in through Facebook and all my progress was still there.

Comment: It did not give me the option to sign in through facebook when I opened the game on my phone.  When I opened Cookie Jam, it did.  I have all progress on that game

Comment: The game is not on facebook, just the app page.  If that makes a difference

Comment: If you will, mark the answer as correct so others who might have this problem can find this and know how to do it!

Answer (score 1):

You play through the new game until you unlock Chris and get to the “Find Better Reception” task.  From here you click on the menu button:

[image: Menu]

This will bring up the TQFS menu, from the menu you tap on Account Info:

[image: Main Menu]

This will open the account settings.  From this list you click on “Sign in As Someone Else”:

[image: Select]

From this list you pick the sign in option you used when you setup your account.  So if you setup an account with Facebook select that, Google choose that, etc.  :

[image: Menu]

For you, since you were signed in with Google, you'll select the Google option.  Then you'll sign in with your information.

Tap next…and voila! My Quahog is back!

[Source](http://familyguyaddicts.com/2014/05/17/where-did-my-game-go/)